# AFNetworking : Cancelled, No Request

Tags: ios, ipad, afnetworking

Dumb question.  I'm just pasting the example AFNetworking code in:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
} failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

But, nothing happens.  If I output operation to NSLog it looks like the request was cancelled:

```
<AFJSONRequestOperation: 0x81655f0, state: isExecuting, cancelled: NO request: <NSURLRequest https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json>, response: (null)>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it looks `cancelled`? The output clearly says `cancelled: NO`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to add a failure block and then inspect the variables provided in that

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks.  The example code references a 404.  Probably should have checked that.

Comment: Gowalla went offline a few weeks ago. The example code in the README will be updated soon.